# How to create an array from an object?

Tags: javascript

I have this object that looks like this:

```
let dataObject = {firstName: "Mike", employeeId: "1020"}
```

and I want to create an array with each property that will look like this:

```
let newArray =  [
{operator:"sum", value: "Mike", property: "firstName", type: "string"}, 
{operator:"sum", value: "1020", property: "employeeId", type:"string"}
];
```

so far I got this:

```js
    let dataObject = {firstName: "Mike", employeeId: "1020"}
    let newArray = Object.keys(dataObject).map((key)=>
       `{${key}}:${dataObject[key]}`
    );
    console.log(newArray);
```

but I'm still not able to get the objects in the array. How to create this array?

Comment: What does the `operator:"sum"` property mean? (would there ever be a case in which a `newArray` item would *not* contain `operator:"sum"`?)

Comment: Well, you need to create the objects in the `map` callback. `.map(key => ({operator: 'sum', property: key, ...}))`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it doesn't mean anything, but I need it in there so I can use it  when send the data to the backEnd

Comment: `Object.keys(dataObject).map(key => ({ operator: 'sum', value: dataObject[key], property: key, type: 'string' }))` but... the requirements seem a bit vague. If you're trying to create an array of objects why are you creating strings? And why are you ignoring the stuff you said you needed to add?

Comment: The result of expression `\`{${key}}:${dataObject[key]}\`` is a *string*. Do you want your array elements to be strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.map` the `entries` of `dataObject`, so you can create another array based on the key and value of each key-value pair in the original object:

```js
const dataObject = {firstName: "Mike", employeeId: "1020"};
const newArray = Object.entries(dataObject).map(([property, value]) => ({
  operator: 'sum',
  value,
  property,
  type: typeof value
}));
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let dataObject = {firstName: "Mike", employeeId: "1020"};

var newArr = Object
  .keys(dataObject)
  .map((key) => {
  return { operate: 'sum', value: dataObject[key], property: key, type: typeof dataObject[key]}
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to map the array to new objects, not to a string representing one.

```
newArray = Object.keys(dataObject).map(key => {
    return {operator:"sum", value: dataObject[key], property: key, type: typeof dataObject[key]};
});
```